# Uptime Monitoring via docker over vpn - cannot access service from container

Tags: networking, docker

### I have the following setup:

- I have VPS with docker installed. lets say it has the IP `100.0.0.1`
- I have a docker container hosting a wireguard installation which is in the "wireguard" docker network and has a fixed IP address of `172.43.0.1`
- I have a docker container hosting an uptime monitoring solution. It is in the same "wireguard" docker network and has the fixed IP address of `172.43.0.100`. It has a static route to `192.168.200.0/24 via 172.43.0.1`
- The VPN uses `192.168.200.0/24`
- I have two VPN clients, my mac `192.168.200.2` which runs a simple http echo server on :8000 and my iphone (`192.168.200.3`) which for the time of the test is not connected to my wifi

### The following things work:

- My iPhone can access the echo server via the VPN
- The wireguard docker container can access the echo server via the VPN
- the docker host can access the access server via the VPN
- the uptime monitoring container can `ping 192.168.200.2` and gets a response
- the mac can `ping 172.43.0.100` (uptime container) and gets a response

### what does not work:

when I run `curl http://192.168.200.2:8000` inside of the uptime monitoring container, (or `telnet 192.168.200.2 8000`) the TCP connection cannot be established (it waits forever and then timeouts)

### What I have checked already:

- host has a firewall, but I have disabled it for the test
- vpn container has a firewall, but it accepts all
- MTU is 1500 everywhere

any ideas what else I could do to fix it? The goal is that I have some services in a private network over which I only have access via the VPN and I want to monitor their status